# Django Tastypie Prefix URL resource with slug

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I am trying to build an API as the following:

```
api/v1/<client_slug>/track/expenses
```

However, I don't really have any data that I need returned at `/clients`, at least at this point, so I was hoping to avoid having to create a ClientResource to follow REST standards.  Below is an example of my ExpenseResource.

```
class ExpenseResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'expenses'
        queryset = Expense.objects.all() # Wish to filter by client_slug
        include_resource_uri = False

        authentication = OAuthTokenAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization() # allow GET/PUT/POST/DELETE/PATCH

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^track/(?P<resource_name>%s)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'), name='api_dispatch_list'),
            url(r"^track/(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name='api_dispatch_detail'),
        ]
```

What is the best way to handle including the **client_slug** into my `ExpenseResource`?  I would like to filter my expenses by the provided **client_slug**, how should I go about doing so?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple actually. You could either override `base_urls()` or use `override_urls()` or `prepend_urls()` to provide customized URLs accepting `client_slug`.

For each resource Tastypie does the following:

```
def base_urls(self):
    """
    The standard URLs this ``Resource`` should respond to.
    """
    # Due to the way Django parses URLs, ``get_multiple`` won't work without
    # a trailing slash.
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'), name="api_dispatch_list"),
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/schema%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_schema'), name="api_get_schema"),
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/set/(?P<pk_list>\w[\w/;-]*)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('get_multiple'), name="api_get_multiple"),
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
    ]
```

what you need is the following:

```
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<client_slug>\w+)/(?P<resource_name>%s)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_list'), name="api_dispatch_list"),
        url(r"^(?P<client_slug>\w+)/(?P<resource_name>%s)/schema%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_schema'), name="api_get_schema"),
        url(r"^(?P<client_slug>\w+)/(?P<resource_name>%s)/set/(?P<pk_list>\w[\w/;-]*)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('get_multiple'), name="api_get_multiple"),
        url(r"^(?P<client_slug>\w+)/(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
    ]
```

just use one of the mentioned methods to provide those and then I believe that `client_slug` will be available in `kwargs[ 'client_slug' ]` in all the Tastypie's methods which accept `**kwargs`.

I haven't tested it but given:

```
 objects = self.obj_get_list(request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
```

in `get_list()` it might even filter the expenses by client for you out of the box.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your suggestion. :) I'm tied up in something else at the moment, but when I get a chance I will look into this and let you know how it went! (and likely accept your answer) :)

Comment: Sounds good. There are few things which could go wrong but I think the general direction should be good, so yes please let me know how it went and I'll be happy to help you with any issues.

Comment: It's been awhile, but I cannot seem to get this to work. I've setup my ExpenseResource to implement override_urls and have setup the URLs as you have defined above.  I seem to still be able to hit /api/v1/expenses/, but get a 404 when I hit /api/v1/client_slug/expenses/.  It's like the URL never registers with Django.  Any ideas?

Comment: It was an issue with the REGEX and my middleware - red herring.  Thanks for your answer, for the most part did the trick!